# test 0.5A inductive load through switch circuit

Tags: switches, testing, inductive

We are a switch component manufacturer and typically run life cycle tests with resistive loads through our switch circuits.  Can someone recommend a circuit diagram set up to test an inductive load through same circuits?  Typical ratings 2.0A resistive, 0.5A inductive.

Comment: Interesting question. Edit your question to elaborate some more. I imagine voltage would matter, for instance. The 2 A resistive test should be easy enough. What about the inductive? Purely inductive or what series resistance. DC or AC? As a matter of interest, how do you actuate the switches in repetitive testing?

Comment: Are you looking to create strong ring wave? They are nasty to switch's in that they cause arcing at the switch contacts. Is this a new test method for you?

Comment: Please do research, A quick google search yields some ideas about this kind of testing https://www.google.com/search?q=switch+inductuive+test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 please also see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look at datasheets for power MOSFETS or IGBTs. They often have the schematic for how they test switching inductive loads. These may not be appropriate for your switches, though.